# Using the boot pins as GPIO's if automatic bootloader is selected

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, esp8266, esp32, esp-idf

I am creating a PCB in which I am using esp32 chip and the chip comes with the serial bootloader so according to the documentation, I can either tie the boot pins to VCC and GND as mentioned or I can use automatic bootloader to enter in the serial bootloader (ROM bootloader) using esptool.py. I decided to use the automatic bootloader So I want to know can i use the boot pins as the GPIO pins without any issues later during the operation?

The link below is the documentation link.
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/esp32/advanced-topics/boot-mode-selection.html#manual-bootloader

Comment: what does the datasheet of the IC say about the capabilites of that boot pin?

Comment: @Marcus Müller There states are defined but in the automatic bootloader part there is no mention of them. So i was wondering what will happen if i connect these pins to a sensors I/O before powering it up because these pins are necessary for booting.

Answer (score 0):

On most targets the boot pins are only sampled during the execution of the bootloader. Then execution is then handed to the customer firmware and the pins are free to use.

> Startup code called from the reset vector determines the boot mode by checking GPIO_STRAP_REG register for bootstrap pin states. Depending on the reset reason, the following takes place:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/startup.html

Comment: After the booting stage we can use but during the startup if the pins are already connected to a sensors I/O pins or to something else instead of the known state mentioned in the document then will it not boot properly?

Comment: Actually i am designing the board from the scratch so i think i can only tie them to the VCC or GND as mentioned in the datasheet but later on i cant use them as GPIO's because they wouldn't be available.

Comment: @Ahsan yes, one of the difficulties of using these pins is their state during bootup…